# DrawerLayout#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, drawerlayout, onmeasure

I got a crash on Firebase
(full crash report: Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
View with id 2131362298: androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()) which I can't succeed to reproduce.
that happens in different devices (Galaxy Tab A7, Galaxy S21 5G, Lenovo Tab P11, etc.) and in different OS (android 10, 11, 12, 13). our minSdkVersion=21 and targetSdkVersion=33.
Does anyone have an idea how can I reproduce this crash?